# MAC Address Registration

Tags: mac

I can't understand the wierd pricing of IEEE MAC address:

A 12bit IAB is $645, getting you 4096 addresses.

While a 24bit OUI is only $1,885.

I notice alot of companies buy multiple 12bit IAB's, which greatly surpass the cost of a single 24bit OUI. Why? What am I missing here? Can OUI's only be used on internal lans?

Comment: I am not an expert on this, so I am just going to answer your last question.  I work for a smallish tech company that bought their own OUI, its very public, and looking up the MAC does return the company name.

Comment: @Myforwik: I don't know why those companies are doing that, it's totally unreasonable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: I believe it's entirely on-topic because it is about electronic design *practice* - having to deal with IAP/OUI is just as much of an "environment constant" as having to deal with this peculiar form of LF AC mains current at some weird 110V.

Answer (score 3):

You're not really missing anything.

Some organizations release only a handful of bespoke automation devices (often reflashing a generic OEM MAC), while some are full OEMs, launching high-volume products.

Finally, some organizations are both, and may have budgeting requirements that make it easier to purchase an IAB for a project/product line, than to coordinate internal use of a company-wide OUI. IAB's also allow you to advertise different brand identities for each project/product.

Comment: What I found out is - you can buy multiple IAB's for the one price. Its a 'gentlemens' agreement thing where everyone is playing nice to try and minimise address space use. eg. they will give me 12,000 address for $645.